# How do I repeat or tile a numpy array but change the value in one element each time it is tiled?

Tags: numpy, repeat, tile

Let's say there is a numpy array 
`a = [1,1,1,0]`

I want to tile or repeat this array 3 times, but make the last element increase by 1 every time it is tiled/repeated.

That is, I want

```
result = [[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2]]
```

in the end.

I think I saw someone use a function to do this, but I cannot remember what that function was.
Or I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0])

#how often to repeat the array along first dimension?
b = 20

#repeat b times along first dimension, one time along second
x = np.tile(a, (b,1)) 

print(x)

#just some consecutive numbers
y = np.arange(20)
print(y)

#overwrite fourth column of array
x[:, 3] = y

print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also treat `result` as a list first and once you get the desired array change it to numpy.

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
result = np.array([[1, 1, 1, i] for i in range(n)])
print(result)
# >>> [[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2]]
```